# using defines in assembly

Tags: c, assembly, preprocessor, avr

I'm trying to do some preprocessing in assembly using the imagecraft compiler avr. So far my best guess looks like this:

```
#define TEST 1
#if TEST == 1
ldi R20, 0xFF
#else
ldi R20, 0xF1
#endif
```

However doing this gives the compiler error:

```
absolute expression expected
```

How do I resolve this or is there a better way to do this?

kenneth

Comment: Try `ldi R20, $FF` instead of `ldi R20, 0xFF` ?

Comment: Edit out the answer from your question and then add it as a proper answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>*Create an answer like this:*</sup>

After some digging I've found the correct solution. Appearently iccavr reserves the .define derective to declare alias' to registers, so above if actually resolved to

```
.if R1 == 1
```

which generated the error message. The solution is to declare a symbolic constant instead of a define using the syntax:

```
TEST = 1
```

Then it works as intended.

Comment: Oh, ok. I just didn't want it to seem like I had posted a fake question.

Comment: Posting "fake" questions are actually OK, as long as they are on topic. It is a way to increase knowledge and help others with the same problem you had.

Comment: To give credit where credit is due, that whole answer above is Kenneths, verbatim!